# How to make dynamic positions in Spritkit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I only have a scene with following variables:

```
widthOfScene = self.size.width
heightOfScene = self.size.height
var constLabelPosition = CGPoint(x:witdhOfScene*0.6, y: heightOfScene*0.95)
var dynamLabelPosition = CGPoint(x: constLabelPosition.x * 0.1, y: constLabelPosition.y)
```

I want my dynamLabel to be just always 10% right of my constLabel even if I decide to change the `constLabelPosition` in a few months.
My code is not working. `dynamLabel` is always just in the middle of the `constLabel`...is there a way to implement such dynamic label position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this seems like a simple miscalculation of x position of  dynamicLabelPosition.

You sure you didn't mean :

```
var dynamLabelPosition = CGPoint(x: constLabelPosition.x + constLabelPosition.x * 0.1, y: constLabelPosition.y)
```

Comment: or just multiply by 1.1 and avoid the addition